# What's the math behind moving from a starting point in the direction of another one?

Tags: google-maps, geometry, gps, wgs84, mathematics

I am working with decimal-degree coordinates for a software and lack geographic background.

I want to convert the coordinates to a grid to calculate distances and then move around using standard geometry.

The coordinate format is the same used in Google Maps urls (decimal WGS 84) which is not a Cartesian plane.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the coordinates of intermediate steps when traveling from a point to another with known a speed and start/finish points.

How do I translate a coordinate, given a bearing (in the form of a destination point) by some amount of meters?

Is there an angular equivalent of the *line from two points* function that I can use to get all the intermediate points?

[image: the line equation from two points]

**Update**: I am working with city-level distances (~10km max) in Italy. I tried to use Cartesian operations on the WGS 84 coordinates directly: the result in this case is good enough. I lose some millimeters on movements but it does not really matter for my implementation, since in the end the position will be exactly the one I want.

Still, I asked this question in order to comprehend the necessary math operations to translate coordinates either directly or by converting to a 2D plane, doing operations and converting back (without loss of data, possibly).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which details how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. You have a number of topics here, without much indication of initial research. While there is a WGS 1984 geographic coordinate system, there doesn't appear to be a WGS98 (nor WSG 98).  All geographic coordinate systems are ***angular*** not Cartesian, and inappropriate for plane geometry equations. Unfortunately, you've encountered the [Second Geodetic Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems); I'd recommend using a software library.

Comment: Well, for a small area a linear approximation may be good enough.

Comment: Thanks Vince. I followed lynxlynxlynx suggestion and found it to work for city-level navigation (thanks to you too). I edited the question to be more clear, tough.

Answer (score -1):

There is a Cartesian plane version of WGS84 known as web Mercator or spherical Mercator.

[GEographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) can help to convert them. Then the formula you mentioned can be used to find intermediate points

Comment: Web Mercator should not ever be used for distances, even close to the Equator.